# Device and network interface

Tags: linux, networking

I have wifi and ethernet card in my computer.

Under linux is there a way to know which device is using which network interface?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can run command "ip a" and check all the network interfaces connected: from the name of the interface you can see which kind of connection it's related to the interface, i.e.:

```
eth0
```

Some kind of cabled connection

```
wlp1
```

Some kind of wireless connection

This applies to default names, since you can always change the interface name.